# Find the code which hide the top links

Tags: magento-1.9, layout, template, toplinks

we have top links in our [site1](http://sb1.collagekingapp.com/) as below

```
store view switcher,  My Cart, Checkout, Register, Log In
```

for some reason we removed it and made it like [site2](http://sb2.kidsdial.com/)

we want to know what code is removing the top links, because we want to display those links again.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well, it's hard to guess just by looking at the website.

It's **definitely not CSS** so it could be one of those two possibilites

**Removed via XML** : if you have a `local.xml` file, the following code removes the top links:

```
<remove name="top.links" />
```

**Removed via PHTML** : open your `app/design/<your_package>/<your_theme>/template/page/html/header.phtml` and look for the following code:

```
<?php echo $this->getChildHtml('topLinks') ?>
```

Or

```
<?php echo $this->getChildHtml('top.links') ?>
```

If you can't find it, that means that's how the top links have been removed and you need to add that code back to the template.